# A method that applies self to a proc

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, proc-object

I want to have a method defined on `Object` that takes a block and applies the receiver to the block. An implementation will be like the following:

```
class Object
    def apply &pr; pr.call(self) end
end

2.apply{|x| x * 3} # => 6
```

Is there already a standard way to do this or a well known library that has a method with similar use? If so, I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

It happens to me very often that, I have a method that takes an optional block, and when there is no block, I want to return some `return_value` calculated within the method, but when there is a block, I want to return the return value of the `return_value` applied to the block. For now, I have bunches of lines like:

```
def method ..., &pr
  ...
  pr ? pr.call(return_value) : return_value
end
```

but I want to consistently write

```
def method ..., &pr
  ...
  pr ? return_value.apply(&pr) : return_value
end
```

or even better, with a slightly modified definition of `apply`,

```
def method ..., &pr
  ...
  return_value.apply(&pr)
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to introduce a new dependency when the small function listed above accomplishes your goal?

Comment: @maerics If there is a built in way, I want to use that.

Comment: Why not just use a lambda? `f = ->(x) { x * 3 }; six = f[2]`

Comment: @muistooshort Actually, that is not good.

Comment: Looks like you might have your blocks in the wrong place. Why not just return the value and let the caller do what they want with it?

Comment: Is that not identical to `def apply; yield self; end` ?

Comment: @steenslag Yes. It is. I want to have that effect with `self` as the receiver.

Comment: ActiveSupport has [the try method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) defined on object. It also takes a method. The trick is it's  defined on [nil](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/82d41c969897cca28bb318f7caf301d520a2fbf3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L28) to return nil. Apart from that, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `Object.tap` is what you are looking for:

```
"Abc".tap do |str|
  puts str
end
```

Comment: `tap` also has the side effect of returning the object you're tapping, which may or may not be desired (it's useful for inserting calls into method chains), but is slightly different from the original request

Comment: `tap` is also a Ruby 1.9 method and needs to be monkey-patched into Ruby 1.8 if backward compatibility is an issue

Comment: Re: Ruby 1.9 - not really, it's present in 1.8.7.

Comment: @AleksanderPohl Actually as Gareth writes, this is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, there is a little difference between `tap` and your method - the returned value. I haven't spotted it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that not identical to `def apply; yield self; end`? – steenslag
>
> @steenslag Yes. It is. I want to have that effect with `self` as the receiver. – sawa

Is this what you mean?

```
2.instance_eval { * 3 }
# => 6
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. `instance_eval` simply runs code as if the receiver was `self`. Operators don't presume `self` as the receiver, so you'd actually have to write this:

```
2.instance_eval { self * 3 }
# => 6
```

However, as a proof of concept, this is possible:

```
Numeric.send(:define_method, :plus) { |x| self + x }
2.instance_eval { plus 3 }
# => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

(Aftwer reading OP's edit) AFAIK the canonical way to write this is:

```
def purpose(*args)  #no &bl or &pr
  res = 42 #huge calculation
  return res unless block_given?
  yield res
end

p purpose(1,2)
purpose{|n| puts "from the block: #{n}"}
```