# Is there a `pipe` equivalent in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Occasionally when writing Ruby I find myself wanting a `pipe` method, similar to `tap` but returning the *result* of calling the block with `self` as a parameter, like this:

```
class Object
  def pipe(&block)
    block.call(self)
  end
end

some_operation.pipe { |x| some_other_operation(x) }
```

..but so far I haven't managed to find out what it's called, if it exists. Does it exist?

If it doesn't, I know I could monkey-patch object to add it but, y'know, that's bad. Unless there's a brilliant, guaranteed to never clash (and descriptive and short) name I could use for it...

Comment: `some_operation.brilliant_guaranteed_to_never_clash_name { |x| some_other_operation(x) }`

Comment: How is this different than `some_other_operation(some_operation)`?

Comment: it isn't, but it allows you to chain operations in a less ugly way. So you avoid things like `some_other_operation(some_operation(x))`

Comment: `some_operation(x).pipe { |y| some_other_operation(y) }` is less ugly than simply making two method calls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A method that applies self to a proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591131/a-method-that-applies-self-to-a-proc)

Comment: @willglyn, yes, I think so: `baz(bar(foo(x)))` or `foo(x).pipe(&:bar).pipe(&:baz)`

Comment: It also allows you to write the methods in the order they'll be applied.

Comment: Your last example isn't exactly equivalent; the receiver of `baz`/`bar`/`foo` is self in one, while the receiver is the result of the method chain in the other.

Comment: @willglynn eh? can you explain a bit more? as far as I can see they're exactly equivalent.

Comment: Ah, no, you're right. I withdraw that statement.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423061/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This abstraction doesn't exist in the core. I usually call it `as`, it's short and declarative:

```
class Object
  def as
    yield(self)
  end
end

"3".to_i.as { |x| x*x } #=> 9
```

[Raganwald](http://raganwald.com/) usually mentions that abstraction in his posts, he calls it [into](https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2008-10-30/thrush.markdown).

So, summing it up, some names: `pipe`, `as`, `into`, `peg`, `thru`.

Comment: I used to call it apply. Now I call it chain.

Comment: Hmmm. It's a difficult one to name. Nothing seems to feel quite right.

Comment: Considered harmful... goto ? :)

Comment: I finally decided on `peg`.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 2.5 [introduced Object.yield_self](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6721) which is exactly the pipe operator you're using: it receives a block, passes self as the first argument to it and returns the result of evaluating the block.

```
class Object
  def yield_self(*args)
    yield(self, *args)
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
"Hello".yield_self { |str| str + " World" }
# Returns "Hello World"
```

You can also read a little more about it in the following blog posts:

1. [Explains the difference with Rails' try and Ruby's tap methods](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/12/12/ruby-2-5-added-yield_self.html)
2. [Some very nice examples of using yield_self to simplify code](https://mlomnicki.com/yield-self-in-ruby-25/)

Comment: It would be great if we could get this bumped to the accepted answer. Every supported version of Ruby today supports yield_self.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the the technique I use to chain objects. It's pretty much exactly as above except I don't reopen the `Object` class. Instead, I create a `Module` which I will use to extend whatever object instance I'm working with. See below:

```
module Chainable
  def as
    (yield self.dup).extend(Chainable)
  end
end
```

I've defined this method to prohibit mutative methods from altering the original object. Below is a trivial example of using this module:

```
[3] pry(main)> m = 'hi'
=> "hi"
[4] pry(main)> m.extend(Chainable).as { |m| m << '!' }.as { |m| m+'?'}
=> "hi!?"
[5] pry(main)> m
=> "hi"
```

If anybody sees anything wrong with this code, please let me know! Hope this helps.