# Ruby method chaining - `tap` with replacement

Tags: ruby, function, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a `pipe` equivalent in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848967/is-there-a-pipe-equivalent-in-ruby)

I'm looking at the `tap` method in Ruby - but unfortunately the object returned from the passed block is not passed on. What method do I use to have the object passed on?

Here's what I'm trying to (unsuccessfully) do:

```
obj.tap{ |o| first_transform(o) }.tap{ |o| second_transform(o)}
```

This is, of course, equivalent to `second_transform(first_transform(o))`. I'm just asking how to do it the first way.

Doing this is trivial with lists:

```
list.map{ |item| first_transform(item) }.map{ |item| second_transform(item)}
```

Why isn't it as easy with objects?

Comment: Why is it unsuccessful? What happens?

Comment: `tap` ignores / discards the value returned from the `first_transform` and `second_transform` methods. It's built to observe objects while inside a chain, not participate in the chain itself. This works only if the `transform` methods mutate the object itself.

Comment: “This is, of course, equivalent to `second_transform(first_transform(o))`”. No, it’s not, it is equivilant to `first_transform(o); second_transform(o);`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Only if the transform functions mutate the object. If they did then `tap` would work fine, and the question would be moot.

Comment: @sawa It actually is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing that out... I'm voting to close as dup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Object
  def as
    yield self
  end
end
```

With this, you can do `[1,2,3].as{|l| l << 4}.as{|l| l << 5}`

Comment: Hmm. Why isn't this in Ruby core? It's not that complex and it's really useful.

Comment: And this is why I'm waiting for namespaces. Easier to monkeypatch inside a class.

Comment: Please try and avoid using keywords as method names, though

Comment: Of course in your example, nothing would change if `do` were replaced with `tap`. I’d also say it’s not in core because it’s *not* very useful—this example is a very verbose way of saying `[1, 2, 3] << 4 << 5`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: In fact it's a pretty useful function abstraction (a lot of people use it with different names `into`, `as`, `pipe`, ...). A more real example: `surface = length.as { |width, height| weight*height }`. It's useful to chain values in a OOP flow (left-to-right). Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848967/is-there-a-pipe-equivalent-in-ruby

Comment: Call it `pipe` or `chain`. Or maybe `filter`.

Comment: @tokland Interesting, your example is a little better, though I think I’d usually prefer a full-on method. Though I can see the use in a one-liner.

Comment: Ruby >= 2.5 introduces `Object#yield_self` which does exactly what OP wants. The answer would be `obj.yield_self{ |o| first_transform(o) }.yield_self{ |o| second_transform(o)}`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is `tap` doesn't do what you think it does.

`tap` is called on an object and will always return that same object.

As a simple example of `tap`s use

```
"foo".tap do |foo|
  bar(foo)
end
```

This still returns `"foo"`

In your example you have an object, and you want to apply two functions to it in succession.

```
second_transform(first_transform(obj))
```

---

UPDATED:

So I guess I'd ask why you want to chain in this way.

```
obj.do{|o| first_transform(o)}.do{|o| second_transform(o)}
```

Is that really more clear than

```
second_transform(first_transform(obj))
```

Lets take an example I often use

```
markdown(truncate(@post.content))
```

or

```
truncated_post = truncate(@post.content)
markdown(truncated_post)
```

I guess it depends on the nature of your `transform`

Comment: I'm sorry to be pedantic, but this looks like a simple restatement of the question itself :-/

Comment: @SudhirJonathan Indeed it is merely a restatement, but it is true that your question was badly worded so that it needed a restatement.

Answer (score -1):

You could also consider to make `#first_transform` and `#second_transform` instance methods of the item's class (and return the transformed item of course).

These methods definitions should look like this:

```
class ItemClass
  # If you want your method to modify the object you should
  # add a bang at the end of the method name: first_transform!
  def first_transform
    # ... Manipulate the item (self) then return it
    transformed_item
  end
end
```

This way you could simply chain the methods calls this way:

```
list.map {|item| item.first_transform.second_transform }
```

It even reads better in my humble opinion ;)

Comment: Yup, that would, but I don't want to change the classes - even more so when they're standard Ruby objects / hashes / lists.

Comment: You don't have to change standard Array/Hashes, you have to change your items' class. I'm assuming these items are of a class of your because usually in ruby standard classes methods are chainable (e.g. `'a string'.upcase.reverse`)

Comment: That's exactly the problem - standard transformations like `upcase` and `reverse` are chainable. What about custom transformations? How do you make them chainable?

Comment: It's exactly what I said, you have to write your custom methods must return the item after modifying it. It would be even better if these transformation are instance methods of the items' class so you keep the transformations coupled with your item's class.